# FNR.exe - How to find and replace an entire line with the computer date

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to replace an entire line in an XML file however I am not able to identify how to do it with the Tool `FNR.exe`.

I have the following `.bat` created by FNR:

```
cd C:\Processes\copy nFe

"C:\Processes\fnr\fnr.exe" --cl --dir "C:\Processes\xml_original" --fileMask "*.xml" --includeSubDirectories --useRegEx --find "<dhEmi>" --replace "1" > replacedinfo.txt

copy C:\Processes\xml_original\*.xml C:\Processes\xml_modificado
```

This is the original xml file:

```
<dhEmi>2019-10-23T07:31:25-03:00</dhEmi>
```

When I use the .bat created by FNR the result I have is this one:

```
12019-10-23T07:31:25-03:00</dhEmi>
```

What I expect is to have the entire line modified by the actual date of the computer so if now it is 10:15 AM that only the part regarding the time which in the example is `07:31:25` becomes `10:15:20`. As below:

```
<dhEmi>2019-10-23T10:15:20-03:00</dhEmi>
```

Thank you.

Comment: That's strange, what I expact to happen is to `find` `<dhEmi>` and `replace` it with `1`. That is exactly what appears to be happening. This site is not somewhere where you just post code that makes no attempt at the task at hand, then asks for it to be made to perform that task.

Comment: I have tried a lot of things but none seems to be working:
first of all I was trying to use the 1 as a standard to see how I was able to get the information from the entire line. I have tried:

<pre>... --useRegEx --find "$'<dhEmi>" --replace "date  \t"...<code>

But no results were found. My apologies, I forgot to mention this into the main post.

Comment: Unfortunately this site assists you with your problematic code. Please post the code you've tried inside your question body, using the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58523905/edit) button. However, please note that not having made much of an attempt at coding for the actual script based upon your own research will not often be met with much enthusiasm.

Comment: What is `fnr.exe`?